# macOS: avoid that Qt modal dialog (QDialog, QWizard) covers everything with LSUIElement=1

Tags: macos, qt, modal-dialog

I'm working on a Qt 5.9 application (actually, PyQt, but I'm relatively sure the problem is with Qt itself). On mac OS X, I discovered that QDialogs with setModal(true) or QWizards (which are modal anyway) are always on top of *all* running applications, given that in `Info.plist` (of my app bundle) `LSUIElement` is set to `1` (which hides the application from the dock - which is OK because users access my program via a tray icon). It behaves fine (other foreground windows *do cover* my application as intended) when `LSUIElement != 1`.

Are there any special windowFlags I need to set for those dialogs? Or is this simply a Qt bug?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Objective-C

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void QMacUtils::MakeWindowTopmost( QWidget* widget, bool topmost )
{
    id nsviewObject = reinterpret_cast<id>( widget->winId() );
    id nsWindowObject = [nsviewObject window];
    if( topmost )
    {
        [nsWindowObject setLevel:NSModalPanelWindowLevel];
    }
    else
    {
        [nsWindowObject setLevel:NSNormalWindowLevel];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether I want to apply such a drastic hack. My application behaves fine when LSUIElement is not set (or 0), so I'm just trying to understand why the behavior changes when using LSUIElement = 1.